# Кнопка переключения полной версии сайта и мобильной

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Собственно нужно сделать кнопку, которая переключает с адаптивной версии сайта на полную. То есть управлять viewport и отключать media queries. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно при клике на кнопку убирать из мета-тега вьюпорта `width=device-width`, необходимое для срабатывания медиа-выражений, и менять его на, например, `width=1200`.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
  viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=1200');
});
```

```html
<button>Switch to full version</button>
```

Comment: Бред. Viewport тут не поможет. Meta теги рендаряться еще на этапе загрузки html. Тем более ваш пример не работает. Проверили хотя бы.

Comment: К тому же, по правильному стили пишут Mobile First, то есть изначально стили пишутся как раз для мобильной версии. Так что ваш вариант неприемлем.

Comment: вы сделали сразу несколько предположений, одно из них неверное, другое - необоснованное мнение.
что касается динамической смены вьюпорта - вы проводили исследования? вот например статья еще 2011-го года http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2011/06/dynamically_cha.html
кстати, как вы ожидали сработает поиск вьюпорта в сниппете? очевидно, что здесь будет выдавать ошибку.

Comment: Я тоже умею ссылками разбрасываться http://lpgenerator.ru/blog/2016/03/16/strategiya-mobile-first-chto-eto-i-pochemu-na-nego-stoit-obratit-vnimanie/

Comment: эта ссылка не имеет ничего общего с объективными правилами написания кода. вы мне лучше докажите, что мой вариант не работает (можно даже ссылкой) и объясните на каком объективном основании минусуете ответ.

Comment: И даже в вашем примере написано, что это делают не все браузеры "Opera, Dolfin for bada, BlackBerry, Firefox, IE and Obigo do not."

Comment: Так что в данном случае неверные советы даете здесь именно вы. И за это минусую. За ответы, в которых есть подводные камни.

Comment: "не имеет ничего общего с объективными правилами написания кода" 
Смеюсь. Самый первый пример, который приходит в голову - даже при приеме на работу, первым делом спрашивают об этом приеме. Любой хороший CSS-разработчик знает, что хорошей практикой является MobileFirst-стили. Просто даже логически это более верно.

Answer (score 1):

Тут несколько вариантов:

- Самый простой  и понятный(хоть и не совсем отвечающий требованиям) - просто редиректить, кинув какой-нибудь маяк на будущее в куки, ибо кто то может захотеть открыть в новой вкладке, скинуть другу, или скинуть себе на мобилку, и сразу открыть там его в мобильной версии. Это более юзер-френдли.
- При нажатии добавить в body/(ко всем переключаемым элементам) класс `%classname%`, переписать селекторы в `css` под него.
- При нажатии, в `head` у линка на файл стилей `href` - поменять на урл к файлу, для определенной версии сайта. Костыльно, лагуче, и вообще неприемлимо, как по мне.

Comment: Все ваши варианты костыльные, как по мне.

Comment: @Vadizar - потому что это решение в принципе костыльно. Кому в здравом уме может понадобиться переключение сайта в динамике с полной на адаптивную версию? Также, 3й вариант во многом повторяет твой, те же яйца, только в профиль. И да, MobileFirst -уместен там, где он необходим, далеко не все и не вся следуют этому алгоритму.

Comment: @SLy_huh есть куча сайтов с подобным функционалом. Вот только реализовано это там через редирект на мобильную версию. А вариант с меда двери - очень даже ничего. Лучше редиректа. Кстати, в мобильном Safari по-умолчанию есть такой функционал. Работает он на эмуляции "большого" разрешения. Хотите сказать, что в Apple работают люди не в здравом уме?)

Comment: @Vadizar чем лучше? Единственное, это возможность переключить сайт на лету. Но __зачем__? Никто не свапает версии сайтов по 30 раз на дню, чтобы это создавало такую проблему, как перезагрузка сайта.

Comment: @SLy_huh 
1. Меньше ресурсов на поддержку такого вариант.
2. Исключает дубликаты контента для поисковиков.
3. Банальная экономия трафика для мобильных клиентов.
4. Скорость загрузки.

Comment: @vadizar В чем меньше ресурсов? Что мешает индексировать по полным версиям сайта? Какая экономия, если сперва мобильный юзер все равно загрузит __полную версию сайта__? Нужно будет только получить css файл и html, все остальное кешируется. Да и в наше время, экономить на кб для __единичного__ случая - это глупо. Точно глупее костыльных решений. Скорость загрузки можно отнести к предыдущему пункту. На жирных страницах, с перерисовкой всех стилей тот же телефон может нормально лагануть.

Comment: @SLy_huh Ясно...